# Manage website storage durin Angular Universal SSR

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Imagine I have website and I want to save for example website theme color(dark or light) inside local storage or session storage, so that when user refreshes website or chrome, last selected theme will show up.

But how can I reach this kind of implementation when using angular universal ssr? because server doesn't have neither session storage nor local storage, its only in browser. If I implement this logic only inside browser? then there will be flick as server loads different theme and then browser rerenders different one after a second.

Comment: You need to use cookies

Comment: can you explain further how I can use cookies?